# Reading time of arrays with an equal number of elements but of different dimensional

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, multidimensional-array, dimensions

I have 3 array that keep integer values. A array of 4 -dimensional, a array of 2-dimensional, a array of single-dimensional. But the total number of elements is equal to each. I'm going to print on console all the elements in these array. Which one prints the fastest? Or is it equal to printing times?

```
int[,,,] Q = new int[4, 4, 4, 4];
int[,] W = new int[16,16];
int[] X = new int[256];
```

Comment: That probably depends on the mechanism you use to enumerate the leaf values. Why don't you go ahead and test it, measure how different approaches compare?

Comment: I got diffrent time when I test it. For example:
First Try:
Q: 167
W: 170
W: 174
///Second try:
Q: 161
W: 167
W: 159

Comment: [Run your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/): [Benchmarkdotnet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/)

Comment: @KadirBeskardes Perhaps you can update your post with the code your benchmarking?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, there are two main ways you could be iterating over the multi-dimensional arrays.

The first is:

```
int[,] W = new int[16,16];

for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        Console.WriteLine(W[i][j]);
}
```

This method is slower than iterating over the single-dimensional array, as the only difference is that for every 16 members, you need to start a new iteration of the outside loop and re-initiate the inner loop.

The second is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(W[i / 16][i % 16]);
}
```

This method is slower because every iteration you need to calculate both (i / 16) and (i % 16).

Ignoring the iteration factor, there is also the time it takes to access another pointer every iteration.

To the extent of my knowledge in boolean functions*, given two sets of two integers, one of them bigger numbers but both having the same size in memory (as is the case for all numbers of type int in c#), the time to compute the addition of the two sets would be exactly the same (as in the number of clock ticks, but it's not something I'd expect everyone who stumbles upon this question to be familiar with). This being the case, the time for calculating the address of an array member is not dependent upon how big its index is.

So to summarize, unless I'm missing something or I'm way rustier than I think, there is one factor that is guaranteed to lengthen the time it takes for iterating over multidimensional arrays (the extra pointers to access), another factor that is guaranteed to do the same, but you can choose one of two options for (multiple loops or additional calculations every iteration of the loop), and there are no factors that would slow down the single-dimensional array approach (no "tax" for an extra long index).

**CONCLUSIONS:**

That makes it two factors working for a single-dimensional array, and none for a multi-dimensional one.

Thus, I would assume the single-dimensional array would be faster

That being said, you're using C#, so you're probably not really looking for that insignificant an edge or you'd use a low-level language. And if you are, you should probably either switch to a low-level language or really contemplate whether you are doing whatever it is you're trying to in the best way possible (the only case where this could make an actual difference, that I can think of, is if you load into your code a whole 1 million record plus database, and that's really bad practice).

However, if you're just starting out in C# then you're probably just overthinking it.

Whichever it is, this was a fun hypothetical, so thanks for asking it!

*by boolean functions, I mean functions at the binary level, not C# functions returning a bool value

Comment: _"This method is slower"_ - citation needed. (I am not saying it isn't.)

Comment: I guess I under-expressed myself. I noticed when you replied. Yes I will use 4 for loops in  4 dimensional array and one for loop in single dimensional array. Actually, I was just wondering about this. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @Fildor, what part are you referring to? Each of the two times I said that phrase, I followed up with an explanation for why I claimed so. If you think one or both of these explanations are insufficient let me know!

Comment: @KadirBeskardes It was nice trying to analyze the problem. One thing I realized later is that it doesn’t take possible compiler optimizations (which I don’t know enough about) into account, so this answer could be wrong. However, may I ask why you were interested in such minor optimizations?

Comment: Referring to both. With such minor (expected-to-be) optimizations, you never know until you run the horses. I've been sure with educated expectations before and benchmark dotnet proved me wrong.

Comment: @Fildor that’s fair! I realized I didn’t take into account compiler optimizations and commented so yesterday. Should I edit my answer to include this disclaimer?

Comment: I think it's clear enough, now.

Comment: Thanks, kinda new to being on this side of stackoverflow